# creating a table from another using CASE expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

Given a table t1 as below

```
+---------+----------+
| bin_val |  bin_cnt |
+---------+----------+
|       0 |        2 |
|       4 |       10 |
|       8 |       15 |
|      12 |       12 |
|      16 |        6 |
|      20 |        1 |
+---------+----------+
```

I need to create a temp table `bin_vals_selected` from table `t1` in Netezza which I do as follows

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE bin_vals_selected as (
  -- statements
) DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM;
```

I need to write the statements to select `bin_val` from `t1` conditionally based on a variable `$bin_selected` which is available in my production interface ( its a simple string replacement before the SQL is passed to Netezza for execution).

What I need in the temp table `bin_vals_selected` is as follows.

When `$bin_selected` = `'all'`, `bin_vals_selected` shall contain all the distinct `bin_val` from `t1`. The statement for this would be as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT bin_val as bin_selected FROM t1
```

When `$bin_selected` = `'first'`, `bin_vals_selected` shall contain the  `bin_val` from `t1` which has the most `bin_count`. The statement for this would be as below.

```
SELECT bin_val as bin_selected FROM t1 ORDER BY bin_cnt DESC LIMIT 1
```

When `$bin_selected` = `'second'`, `bin_vals_selected` shall contain the  `bin_val` from `t1` which has the second most `bin_count`. I'm not sure about how to write the statement for this.

I'm approaching this with a `CASE` expression to create the table based on the value of variable `$bin_selected` - however it is not working.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE bin_vals_selected AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (
    CASE 
      WHEN $bin_selected = 'all' THEN
        (SELECT DISTINCT bin_val AS bin_selected FROM t1 AS a)
      WHEN $bin_selected = 'first' THEN
        (SELECT bin_val AS bin_selected FROM t1 AS a ORDER BY bin_cnt DESC LIMIT 1 )
    END
  )
) DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM;
```

Though the syntax above is for `Netezza` centric (mostly like `Postgres`), a `Postgres` solution would also be helpful since I have local `Postgres` instance to try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by using `group by` and then a condition on that.  You can do this as:

```
select bin_val
from (select bin_val, ,  -- not really needed
             row_number() over (order by bin_cnt desc) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t
where ($bin_selected = 'all') or
      ($bin_selected = 'first' and seqnum = 1) or
      ($bin_selected = 'second' and seqnum = 2);
```

If you want to allow ties when bins have the same count, use `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

Comment: tried this - works well for `all` , however for `first` not getting the expected result `8` ..

Comment: @user3206440 . . . I  modified the answer.  I thought this required aggregation, but it doesn't.  You can just use `bin_cnt` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to do it with a single SQL, you can use UNIONs similar to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bin_val as bin_selected 
FROM t1
WHERE 'all' = $bin_selected

UNION ALL

SELECT bin_val as bin_selected
FROM (
  SELECT bin_val, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY bin_cnt DESC) AS BinCountRank
  FROM t1
) src
WHERE BinCountRank = 1
AND 'first' = $bin_selected

UNION ALL

SELECT bin_val as bin_selected
FROM (
  SELECT bin_val, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY bin_cnt DESC) AS BinCountRank
  FROM t1
) src
WHERE BinCountRank = 2
AND 'second' = $bin_selected
```

It's not very efficient, but it should do the trick.  It does give you flexibility for your source queries.  You may have to mess around with the RANK() to handle any ties.  It also assumes that each query in your string of UNIONs returns the exact same # columns with the same data types.

For your case, I'd use Gordon's answer above...it's much cleaner and faster.